# Checksum validation failed, expected <!DOCTYPE but is .... from bitbucket for https://adress/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml

Tags: maven, bitbucket, pom.xml

I want to have dependency from another private bitbucket repository.
pom.xml in my project that i want to take dependency from is:

```
    <groupId>xyz</groupId>
    <artifactId>name</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
.
.
.
         <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>single</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.name.MainClass</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

And pom.xml of the project where i want to use this dependency:

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>xyz</groupId>
            <artifactId>name</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
.
.
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <archive>
                                <manifest>
                                    <mainClass>com.xyz2.MainClass</mainClass>
                                </manifest>
                            </archive>
                            <descriptorRefs>
                                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                            </descriptorRefs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
.
.
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>bitbucket</id>
            <name>Bitbucket Packages</name>
          <url>https://path/bitbucket/projects/project/repos/xyz</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

and in my maven settings.xml i have:

```
 <server>
      <id>bitbucket</id>
      <username>my_username</username>
      <password>my bitbucket access token</password>

    </server>
```

The xyz project from where I want my dependency builds properly, of course when i have it in my .m2 it works but if not i have :

```
Downloading from bitbucket: https://adress/projects/repos/xyz/package/x-y-z/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Checksum validation failed, expected <!DOCTYPE but is 8e9cdf40db76398363fb5de98a80e7f185f9527b from bitbucket for https://adress/projects/repos/xyz/package/x-y-z/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not validate integrity of download from https://adress/projects/repos/xyz/package/x-y-z/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ChecksumFailureException: Checksum validation failed, expected <!DOCTYPE but is 8e9cdf40db76398363fb5de98a80e7f185f9527b
```

I also tried this version of settings.xml

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"

  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

<pluginGroups/>

  <proxies />

  <servers>

<server>
<id>bitbucket</id>
<username>username</username>
<password>accesstoken</password>

</server>

</servers>

<mirrors/>
 
 
<localRepository>/path/.m2</localRepository>
 
 
</settings>
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the Maven client is encountering an issue while attempting to download the checksum file from the remote repository. The logs suggest that the content being returned starts with <!DOCTYPE, which indicates that the response may be an HTML document rather than the expected checksum content.

To troubleshoot this, you can manually check the checksum file by accessing the following URL:

https://address/projects/repos/xyz/package/x-y-z/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml.sha1

Please replace https://address with the actual address of your repository. By visiting this URL, you can verify the content of the .sha1 file. If the content does not appear to be a valid SHA-1 checksum, it could mean that the repository is misconfigured or there is an issue with the server hosting the repository.

It's worth noting that this situation should not cause the build process to fail since Maven treats checksum validation issues as warnings by default, not errors.

If the issue persists, consider checking the remote repository's configuration or contacting the repository's support for further assistance.